# Renaming music files in R

Tags: r, file-rename

I'm trying to rename a number (179) of files which names follow the pattern:

```
"104-jacques_brel-le_diable_(ca_va)-just.mp3 TEST"
...
"1517-jacques_brel-la_cathedrale-just.mp3 TEST"
```

Aiming at an output looking like:

```
"Le diable (ca va).mp3"
...
"La cathedrale.mp3"
```

Problem is I only know of the paste() command...so I could successfully (and stupidly) add the TEST to the name using:

```
filenames <- list.files()
   filenames[180:181] 
   filenames <- filenames[-c(180:181)]

   files_4dgts<-filenames[c(1:14,21:30,35:80)]
   files_3dgts<-filenames[-c(1:14,21:30,35:80)]


   for (i in 1:length(files_3dgts))
   file.rename(files_3dgts[i],paste(files_3dgts[i],"TEST",sep=""))

   for (i in 1:length(files_4dgts))
   file.rename(files_4dgts[i],paste(files_4dgts[i],"TEST",sep=""))
```

Which obviously isn't any kind of solution to my problem.

Comment: Why R to rename files?

Comment: Only program I know for now, had to use it for university at a very low level, and am looking to learn a bit more about it...
Still better than renaming 200 files by hand :)

Comment: If you are on windows, I will suggest this http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php

Comment: yeah,  I'd vote for `man rename`  myself :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
music <- c("104-jacques_brel-le_diable_(ca_va)-just.mp3 TEST", 
           "1517-jacques_brel-la_cathedrale-just.mp3 TEST")

# Remove all the digits and irrelevant words
musicwipe <- gsub("[[:digit:]]*-jacques_brel-|-just| TEST", "", music)
# Replace all underscores with spaces
musicspace <- gsub("_", " ", musicwipe)
# Replace first letter with uppercase letter
musicupper <- sub("^([[:alpha:]])", "\\U\\1", musicspace, perl=TRUE)

#Result
musicupper
[1] "Le diable (ca va).mp3" "La cathedrale.mp3"
```

Comment: @FUB, if this answers your question, do be sure to mark it as "accepted" by clicking on the hollow checkbox next to Sebastian's answer.